# Makefile - replace redundancy with function

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I worked hard to write a good generic makefile to compile many sources located in different directories for many projects, many targets (make will take many arguments in the future). As a beginner with make-tool, I have searched for many examples and I looked to many question to do my work. To build all objects I use the following target:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o:
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo Compiling $(subst $(OBJDIR),,$(@:%.o=%.c))
    @echo -e \t '>' $@
    @$(ARCH)gcc $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF"$(DEPDIR)/$(@F:.o=.d)" -MT"$(@F:%.o=%.o)" -MT"$(@F:%.o=%.d)" $(SRCFLAGS) $(subst $(OBJDIR)/,,$(@:%.o=%.c)) -o $@
```

How can I replace `$(subst $(OBJDIR),,$(@:%.o=%.c))` with a function to get the .c file from .o file? Then target will be like the following:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o:$(call obj_to_src ...)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo Compiling $<
    @echo -e \t '>' $@
    @$(ARCH)gcc $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF"$(DEPDIR)/$(@F:.o=.d)" -MT"$(@F:%.o=%.o)" -MT"$(@F:%.o=%.d)" $(SRCFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Note that my sources have the following structure:

```
$(WORKSPACE)/app/*.c
$(WORKSPACE)/efsl/*.c
$(WORKSPACE)/*/*.c
```

and objects will have this structure:

```
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(subst $(WORKSPACE),,$(SRCS:.c=.o)))
.build/$(PROJECT)/$(CONFIG)/obj/app/*.o
.build/$(PROJECT)/$(CONFIG)/obj/*/*.o
```

For those who are intersted in my makefile I attached it to this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/eu07o41uz3jvb2k/makefile?dl=0

Comment: What about `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c` and then using `$<` in the recipe to refer to the C source file?

Comment: I think there's also a variable that has the % part of the filename which you could use to generate the the dependency filename easier

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I have tried what you suggest to me and it does not work. make: *** No rule to make target *.o will occur

Comment: @ChrisTurner yes you are right, I can use %o:%c but it will not work because source files are located in different directories. And I don't want to use separate make files

Comment: @Abderrezak What directory are the .c files in?  You can write things like `$(SRCDIR)/%.c`.

Comment: Do you mean that your source files are in a directory tree, and you want to build the object files in an identical tree under `$(OBJDIR)`?

Comment: @Beta yes this what I have. I'll modify the question to be more explicit

Comment: @TavianBarnes there are many folder. Look at the question, I added more informations

Comment: Based on your updates don't you want `OBJS = $(subst $(WORKSPACE),$(OBJDIR),$(SRCS:.c=.o))` ? You don't want to have anything like "*.o" in your targets as that'll only work if the .o file already exists.

Comment: @ChrisTurner My update was just to well explain how `OBJS` are generated: in same structure as sources. I want to get back .c from .o target while compiling to use `$<` instead of `$(subst $(OBJDIR)/,,$(@:%.o=%.c))`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using `$(OBJDIR)/%.o:$(WORKSPACE)/%.c`. All sources are located in sub folders under `$(WORKSPACE)`